# this automata is NFA or DFA?

Tags: automata

[image: automata]
That's my question, since it has two symbols but go to a single state, is DFA or NFA?

Comment: DFA. You imagine those as being separate egdes that just happen to go the same state.

Comment: @Jake Your second sentence is correct but this isn't a DFA. A DFA has exactly one transition from each state for each symbol; this automaton has, e.g., no transition for $c$ from $q0$ and no transition for $a$ from $q2$.

Comment: Ah right. I didn't see that $c$ was in the alphabet. My bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, every *deterministic* finite automaton is a fortiori a *non-deterministic* finite automaton. An finite automaton is deterministic if there are no $\epsilon$ moves, and for each state $s$ and alphabet symbol $\alpha$ there is a unique outgoing edge at $s$ labeled $\alpha$. If a finite automaton satisfies this condition, then it you can think of it both as a DFA and as an NFA. If it doesn't satisfy this condition, it is an NFA.